# inflate view returns the old inflated result

Tags: android

I try to inflate a layout multiple times to be inserted inside another layout. Here is the code:

```
    View oldView = null;
    for (ProfileServiceCategory.ProfileService service : profileServiceCategory.getServices()) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.profile_service_list_item, viewHolder.rootView);
        if(oldView == view) {
            Log.d("test", "Error");
        }
        oldView = view;

        TextView serviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_services_name);
        serviceName.setText(service.getServiceValue());
    }
```

The problem that I'm facing is the view variable that is being returned by inflate method is always the first inflated view. To be clear I added a Log.d , if everything worked as expected it should have been never called but it does hit.

I checked the view hierarchy and I can conform that new views in fact has been added to rootView but the reference that I get is for older view.

Comment: I would be reusing the inflater. Move that code out of the for loop. I'm not sure if that will fix your problem tough

Comment: I need to add inflated layout "profileServiceCategory.getServices().size()" times inside the "viewHolder.rootView". By inflating, it adds the inflated layout inside the rootview. That means I can't move it outside the loop. @Bojan

Comment: You do not undesrtand me properly `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);` - this code outside the loop and only use a reference to it `View view = inflater.inflate` in a loop

Comment: Tested same result @Bojan.

Comment: Is that code in some kind of adapter?

Comment: yes it is. It's RecyclerView.Adapter @Naveed

Comment: Then the system might be optimizing the inflation process and reusing the view.  I am not sure about the internals of recycler view but I know its greatly optimized. If your data is being displayed properly then does it really matter if its using the same view?

Comment: No my data doesn't display properly. Notice in code I have "view.findViewById" which looks inside wrong view. And as result it finds wrong subview, which I then use to display some information. @Naveed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my colleague suggested a workaround by adding the view manually to container. Here is the edited code:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);    
    for (ProfileServiceCategory.ProfileService service : profileServiceCategory.getServices()) {    
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_service_list_item, null);   

        TextView serviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_services_name);    
        serviceName.setText(service.getServiceValue()); 

        viewHolder.rootView.addView(view);  
    }
```

When null is getting passed to inflate method as second argument a new view gets returned each time. The view can be inserted inside the container by addView method.

This is obviously a bug in android SDK.

Answer (score -1):

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.profile_service_list_item,
viewHolder.rootView);
```

is always returning the same inflater service. so i think you have to take copy of layoutInflater using `cloneInContext`

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                    .cloneInContext(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, viewHolder.rootView);
```

Comment: Based on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#cloneInContext(android.content.Context) cloneInContext only accepts context as argument. Your example on the other hand accepts int and view. @farhan